# JQuery Slider not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I am trying to duplicate the slider found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6qJC/26/).

I have a file `index.php` and the code is as follows:

**Head:**

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.top {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.testing {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

</head>
```

**Body:**

```
<body>

<div class="top">
  <div class="testing"></div>
</div>

<p>a: <span id="a">0</span>
    <div id="a_slider"></div>
</p>

</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>

    $("#a_slider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        value: 0,
        step: .01,
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#a_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#a").text(ui.value);
        }
    });

</script>
```

But it is not working!  I can only guess that the `jqueryui` link in the head is incorrect, but I'm pretty sure it's the same one as in the fiddle above.

*IF* you supply a fiddle in your solution, please use external resources so I can find the appropriate files.  The simple class and ID names are purely for testing purposes.

**Entire HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.top {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.testing {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="top">
  <div class="testing"></div>
</div>

<p>a: <span id="a">0</span>
    <div id="a_slider"></div>
</p>

</body>

<script>

    $("#a_slider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        value: 0,
        step: .01,
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#a_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#a").text(ui.value);
        }
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I've tried using `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js`, but also no dice.  Below is a screen shot of what shows up...

[image: No Slider]

Notice in the image that no slider shows up.

Comment: (W3c doesn't allow you tu put a div into a p tag).

Comment: Even still, that doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: that's why it was only a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/m6qJC/27/)**

Try loading jQuery UI properly:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

$("#a_slider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        value: 0,
        step: .01,
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#a_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#a").text(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The Fiddle I provided in the question already shows this.  I'm not stuck with the little red box.  I cannot get the slider to show up at all.  Standby for edit (and screenshot) to question...

Comment: It does, yes.  I'm not sure why it doesn't in my code.  I've provided the entire HTML in my question, so please try and run that and see if you can get the slider to show up.

Comment: Still nothing.  Good call on the CSS, I forgot that, but the slider is still not showing up.

Comment: Got it!  Your links need to include `https:` before the `//` but otherwise it's working.  Mod your answer and I'll give you the accept.

Comment: weird, the official documentation doesnt include `https:`

Answer (score 6):

You have to include the jQuery UI stylesheet too:

```
<link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Yup, you're right.  That was exactly the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the jQuery UI touch after jQuery ui:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
```