# Events are not firing in JQuery ui Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, events, slider, onchange

i'm trying to use jquery-ui slider, but all events are not firing (i've tested the `change` and `slide` events), i've tried binding the events via `bind()` but nothing happens, here's my code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="widget-content-range">                              
    <input class="passangers_range" value="0;5" name="passangers_range" />
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(".passangers_range").slider({
    from:1,
    to:5,
    step:1,
    dimension:'',
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.value);
    }
});
```

any ideas please.

Comment: Any error happens in console? Some kind of "undefined"? Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21467371/4730201

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, no there is no errors in the console, i've tried the link you posted and i still have the same problem

Comment: for a test, try to change your element from "input" to a "div" and check out if slider works.

Comment: i've already done that and i still have the same problem, when i remove the `value` attribut i get the following error :  `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` wich i think has nothing to do with the events i'm trying to trigger, i'm using ** jquery 2.2.3**  and  **jquery-ui 1.12.0** if this could be the source of the problem.

Comment: try to create a fiddle with relevant part of the code.

Comment: The convention is to use a `div` element for your slider. How is it supposed to work as `input`? It's supposed to create a handle element as a child, but `input`s don't have children

Comment: the input was included in the template i use, the problem is that it works just fine in a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yqqwxs36/5/) but in my code no, i tried to update the version of jquery-ui the the latest version but i get in the console the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` , i tried to update both jquery and jquery-ui to the latest version and i got the error `Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it, it turns out i had another script (*jquery.slider.min* - **jquery slider plugin**) which overrides the `slider()` function of jquery-ui framework and it uses the `callback()` function to detect the value change of the slider.

thank you very much

Comment: i just removed the unnecessary script

Answer (score 0):

this is working fine for me.

```
jQuery(".passangers_range").on("change", function(event,ui) {
    console.log(event.value.newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (form onChange not triggering when input field value was changed by the slider) but for totally different reasons.

I solved my issue by adding `$('#frm').trigger('change');` to the slider change event.

**HTML**

```
<strong>Speed</strong>
<div class="card">
    <div class="slider" id="speed-slider">
    <div class ="custom-handle ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="speed" value="220" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var speedhandle = $("#speed-slider .custom-handle");
$("#speed-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    max: 255,
    value: 220,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        speedhandle.text(ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        speedhandle.text(ui.value);
        $('input[name="speed"]').val($(this).slider("value"));
        $('#frm').trigger('change');
    }
});
```

I'm pretty sure that's the wrong way of doing it, but for the moment it solved my issue.